# Unable to source zshrc during a terminal emulator's startup

Tags: 16.04, environment-variables, alias, zsh

Installed **Tilix** terminal emulator on **Ubuntu 16.04** virtual machine and configured a json theme to my liking named `theme.json`.

I have added the same environment variables and aliases both in the `.bashrc` and the `.zshrc` as follows:

```
export VAR1=42
alias mydir=/path-to-my-dir/mydir
```

Created a launcher shortcut (`tilix.desktop`) which runs a script (`tilix_launcher.sh`) as follows:

```
# tilix.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Tilix
Comment=Launch Tilix
Exec=/path-to-script/tilix_launcher.sh
Icon=com.gexperts.Tilix
Type=Application

# tilix_launcher.sh
tilix --session /path-to-json/theme.json
```

Confusingly, if on the 'normal' terminal `source` the `zshrc` and then open Tilix, the session has visibility of the zshrc; I do not understand how to automate that within a script (i.e. `tilix_launcher.sh`).

---

**Versions**:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ tilix --version                                                    
Versions
    Tilix version: 1.9.1
    VTE version: 0.42
    GTK Version: 3.18.9
```

The problem is that whenever I launch Tilix (with or without the launcher script), the environment variables and the aliases are *not* known to Tilix's session; have to `source ~/.zshrc` for them to work.

Tried to add this source command within the `tilix_launcher.sh` but it still does not work.

Comment: Tilix != Terminator. I don't see any relation between Tilix and [Terminator](https://github.com/gnunn1/tilix#migrating-settings-from-terminix), and [Tilix's old name was Terminix](https://github.com/gnunn1/tilix#migrating-settings-from-terminix).

Comment: My bad, you are right - auto completion  when I entered the tag failed me. Fixed it, thanks.